# Strange symbols in log-output

Tags: java, logging, logback

I started to see strange output in my log files:

> 2018-11-14 14:04:21,180 [main] [34mINFO[0;39m com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
>   2018-11-14 14:04:21,186 [main] [34mINFO[0;39m com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.`

I don't know what does `[34m` or `[0;39m` mean and why it is here.

My **logback.xml** configuration:

```
 <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>server.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>server.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
      <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
        <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
      </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
      <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
      <charset>UTF-8</charset>
      <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
          <pattern>%d [%thread] (%level) %logger{50} - %msg%n</pattern>
      </layout>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

 <root level="info">
  <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

Comment: http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/1-34mINFO-m-formatting-on-console-output-td5913029.html

Comment: If I undestand correctly it should be some infos related to synthax colouring

Answer (score 2):

Those are escape sequences to color the output. See [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors)